# TextBox not activating Form accept button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form which has a TextBox and a Button. I have set the Form's `AcceptButton` property to my Button, and set the TextBox's `AcceptsReturn` property to `false`:

```
class Window : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private Button btn;
    public Window()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        this.AcceptButton = this.btn;

        textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        textBox1.Width = 50;
        textBox1.AcceptsReturn = false;
        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Test";
        btn.Location = new Point(textBox1.Right + 10, 10);
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Works");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Window());
    }
}
```

However, when pressing the Enter key while the TextBox has focus, the AcceptButton of the Form is not activated. I worked around it using the `KeyDown` event of the TextBox like so:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += (s,e) => { if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) btn.PerformClick(); } ;
```

And although it works I am curious as to why the earlier method using the `AcceptButton` property failed.

Comment: Possibly a typo, but your code sample shows that your `TextBox` has the `AcceptsReturn` set to `true`.

Comment: I wonder this.AcceptButton = this.btn; <=> this.AcceptButton = null; The creation of the button is executed too late.

Comment: Why not let visual studio write all this code for you?

Comment: In a typical windows forms application all this control initialization code is written inside  InitializeComponent function which gets called from constructor. All the code inside InitializeComponent function is auto-generated by visual studio as you continue to set properties of various controls on the form using properties window. Such mishaps will not happen if you follow that route. You possibly tried doing it all by yourself from scratch. When I looked at my auto-generated code it was all good by default.  Hence I was wondering how did you end up creating this problem in first place :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the Form's `AcceptButton` to `btn` before you instantiate it. Move `this.AcceptButton = this.btn;` to any line AFTER `btn = new Button();`.. `btn` is pointing to a null reference up until `new Button()`. Once you instantiate `btn` you can use it to set `AcceptButton`.

Answer (score 2):

You just wrote one line in the wrong place.That's the answer:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Size = new Size(200, 200);

        textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        textBox1.Width = 50;
        textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Test";
        btn.Location = new Point(textBox1.Right + 10, 10);
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        this.AcceptButton = this.btn;
    }
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Very nice catch. Though, it took me a while to figure out which line of code you have moved. Either use line numbers, comments or may be italicize the exact line of code to take reader's attention to that line. You get my +1.

Comment: Good advice @RasikBihariTiwari!
tnx very much!